# How to remove specific row from gridlayout? Rows are added from popup

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I would like to remove specific row from the gridlayout with delete button. Rows are created in popup. Im able to add delete button to each row but cant figure out how to add logic in it.

Here is the codes i have tried. I played with it for a while. I tried it many ways and this is just where i stopped.

Py.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class Row(BoxLayout):
    x1 = StringProperty('')
    x2 = StringProperty('')
    x3 = BooleanProperty(False)
    x4 = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, x1, x2, x3, x4, **kwargs):
        super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.x3 = x3
        self.x4 = x4

    def remove_row(self):
        self.remove_widget(Row)

class MyPopup(Popup):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def fire_popup(self):
        pops = MyPopup()
        pops.open()


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def changescreen(self, value):

        try:
            if value !='main':
                self.current = value
        except:
            print('No Screen named'+ value)




class testiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Hello'

    def add_more(self, x1, x2, x3, x4):
        addbutton = self.root.get_screen('Page2').ids.empty
        addbutton.add_widget(Row(x1, x2, x3, x4))

    def remove(self):
        container = self.root.get_screen('Page2').ids.empty
        if len(container.children) > 0:
            container.remove_widget(container.children[0])

testiApp().run()
```

KV.

```
<MyPopup>:
    id:pop
    size_hint: .4, .4
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: 'XXX!!'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'horizontal'
            Label:
                text:'X1'
            TextInput:
                id: X1

            Label:
                text:'X2'
            TextInput:
                id:X2

            CheckBox:
                id:X3
            Button:
                id:X4
                text:'Delete'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'horizontal'
            Button:
                text:'Lisää'
                on_release: app.add_more(X1.text, X2.text, X3.active, X4)
            Button:
                text: 'Close'
                on_press: pop.dismiss()

<Row>:
    x1:''
    x2:''
    x3:False
    x4:

    Label:
        text: root.x1
    Label:
        text: root.x2
    CheckBox:
        active: root.x3
    Button:
        text:'poista'
        on_release: root.remove_row()


ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen:
        name:'Main'
    SecondScreen:
        name:'Page2'



<MainScreen>:
    name:'Main'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        GridLayout:
            id:container
            cols:2
            Label:
                text:'testfield1'
            TextInput:
                id: textfield1
            Label:
                text:'testfield2'
            TextInput:
                id: textfield2

        Button:
            text:'Next Page'
            on_release: app.root.current ='Page2'




<SecondScreen>:
    name:'Page2'


    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            Label:
                text:'Popup Test'
            ScrollView:
                bar_width: 5
                bar_color: 1,0,0,1 #red
                bar_inactive_color: 0,0,1,1 #blue
                effect_cls: 'ScrollEffect'
                scroll_type:['bars','content']
                GridLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    row_default_height: 60
                    cols:1
                    id:empty
            BoxLayout:
                Button:
                    text:'Open Popup'
                    on_press: root.fire_popup()

                Button:
                    text:'remove'
                    on_release: app.remove()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question 2 - Popup message to confirm delete

> ... want that Poista(Delete) button to open popup asking " are you
>   sure? Yes or No" How should i bind the remove_row?

## Solution

### kv file

- Create a class rule, `<ConfirmDeleteRow>:` with inheritance of [Popup](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html) widget
- The content of the Popup widget is a `Label` widget with text of 'Are you sure?', and two `Button` widgets with text of 'Yes', and 'No' respectively.
- Using `on_release` event to bind the 'Yes' button to invoke `remove_row()` method
- Using `on_release` event to bind both buttons to close the popup window by invoking `dismiss()` method
- Bind the `delete` button to invoke a new method, `confirm_delete()`

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<ConfirmDeleteRow>:    # class rule
    size_hint: .4, .4
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: 'Delete'

    BoxLayout:    # content
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Are you sure?'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            Button:
                text: 'Yes'
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss()
                    root.row.remove_row()
            Button:
                text: 'No'
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss()
...


<Row>:
    x1:''
    ...
    Button:
        text:'poista'
        on_release: root.confirm_delete()
```

### Py file

- Implement `class ConfirmDeleteRow()` with a new class attribute, `row = ObjectProperty(None)` and a constructor accepting an additional parameter, `row`
- Implement a new method, `confirm_delete()` to instantiate `ConfirmDeleteRow()` and pass `self` (i.e. row) as argument

#### Snippets - py file

```
class ConfirmDeleteRow(Popup):
    row = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, row, **kwargs):
        super(ConfirmDeleteRow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.row = row    # save row object


class Row(BoxLayout):
    ...

    def confirm_delete(self):
        confirm_delete_row = ConfirmDeleteRow(self)   # pass self / row object
        confirm_delete_row.open()
```

## Question 1 - remove specific row

> ... would like to remove specific row from the gridlayout with delete
>   button

### Solution

When the button, 'poista' (delete) is pressed, `self` in `remove_row()` method is referring to the instantiated `Row` object for that specific row in the `ScrollView`. Therefore, to remove that specific row, you have to refer to its parent in order to remove it/child from the parent.

Replace `self.remove_widget(Row)` with `self.parent.remove_widget(self)`

## Snippets

```
def remove_row(self):
    self.parent.remove_widget(self)
```

## Output

[image: Before removing second row]
[image: After second row removed]

Comment: In case you would want that Poista(Delete) button to open popup asking " are you sure? Yes or No"  How should i bind the remove_row?

Comment: I receive this error message'ScreenManagement' object has no attribute 'remove_row'. Notice that my remove_row() method is inside Row class. This is the main issue with kivy for me now. I need to learn how to properly refer other instances